# Flex - How can we measure the height of a control with nested renders?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

I'm using a List control. 
In the renderer of the List control I've got a Repeater. 
Each Repeater can have a different number of items. 
Adding to the complexity, one of the components being repeated in the 
repeater is a Text control that has long text that will wrap, 
increasing it's height.

I need to expand the height of the List completely so that there's no 
vertical scrollbar.

How can I do this?

I tried an extremely dirty attempt at calculating the Lists height 
based on the data source. From the data source I can figure out the 
number of repeater items and the number of items in each repeater in 
the List's renderer. But there's no way to compensate for the wrapping 
of the text in the Text control.

Is there a better way (or any way!) to do this? Please help.

Thanks in advance,

zxcvb

Answer (score 0):

This method might help [measureHeightOfItems()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/core/UIComponent.html#getExplicitOrMeasuredHeight%28%29)